# 400 on a POST request but GET works fine

Tags: jmeter, postman

I am trying to do a POST request with postman and jmeter and i get he same results on each when i do a POST request. The website is https://uat-identity.intelliflo.com/core/Identity/Account/Login and i can log in normally (via chrome) but when i try with postman i just keep getting a 400. I have the below setup

[image]

I have all the headers set up as well i got from google developer console under the network tab.

I presumed if i just added a POST request to that endpoint without any credentials i would get an unauthed response and not a 400.

Any help or idea on how to do this would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending wrong `__RequestVerificationToken` parameter value, it is **dynamic** and it is designed for preventing [CSRF attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) so you need to design your test scenario as follows:

1. Open Login page (GET request)
2. Extract  `__RequestVerificationToken` value and store it into the variable
3. Perform login (POST Request) and provide credentials, return url and the aforementioned token from step 2

More information:

- Postman: [How do you use Postman to test Ajax endpoints that are protected with an anti-forgery token](https://www.ankursheel.com/blog/postman-ajax-endpoints-xsrf-tokens)
- JMeter: [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)

Comment: thnaks dmitri, if thats the case shouldnt it bring back a 401 instead of a 400?

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, i got this to work with passing the token from the frst request with a variable onto the second